# AS3/JavaScript ExternalInterface and File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3

I am trying to create a multiple file upload flash application to be called from an External Interface, but it isn't working.

AS3:

```
var fileRef:FileReferenceList;

ExternalInterface.addCallback('selectFiles', showDialog);

 function showDialog()
{
  fileRef = new FileReferenceList();
  fileRef.browse();

//  ExternalInterface.call('ASalert');
}
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var uploader = this['_uploader'];

  $('#selectFiles').click(function(){
    uploader.selectFiles();
  })
})

function ASalert() {
  alert('Fired');
}
```

When I run the script and comment out the fileRef parts and uncomment the alert call, it shows the alert, also when I comment out the ExternalInterface call, leaving only the fileRef parts, it shows the file upload dialog.

When I run it as intended, I get the following error:

```
Error calling method on NPObject
```

Searching google wielded a never ending list of tutorials on either uploading files or using the externalInterface in AS3, but nothing on using them together!

Any ideas?

Comment: Few things I've noticed `fileReferenceList` should probably be `FileReferenceList`, your `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` probably should be a reference to a function and not an anonymous function.

Comment: I know and that was a typo and a quick way of writing it out as I am actually typing this on my phone... like I said, each individual part of it works fine, just not together.

Comment: What is it that your trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to get the multi-file upload dialog box to appear when clicking a HTML element with the ID 'selectFiles' I thought that was obvious due to the fact that the function is called by the ExternalInterface...

Comment: Well it may be "obvious" but that doesn't mean that what I think your trying to do and what you are trying to do are the same thing.

Comment: I see, sorry I was getting a bit frustrated with myself due to the 'security' issue with calling file uploads from JavaScript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your `ExternalInterface.addCallback('selectFiles', showDialog);` statement in a condition that checks for the availability of the ExternalInterface:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('selectFiles', showDialog); 

}
```

Also even if that solves that problem, you're going to run into trouble with this:

```
function showDialog() 
{ 
  fileRef = new FileReferenceList(); 
  fileRef.browse(); 

//  ExternalInterface.call('ASalert'); 
}
```

You can't call the `FileReferenceList.browse()` without some kind of user interaction like a mouse click or key press. There is no way around this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! I was trying to make a HTML5 Fallback for multi-file uploads that didn't change site appearance too drastically but it appears that I won't be able to! I'll just use the Flash upload until HTML5 is better supported I think! You also helped me with my music player, the reason I was doing that so weirdly was to integrate it as a HTML5 fallback too!

Comment: Why don't you just use `<input type="file" />`? If I'm understanding you correctly, that doesn't require HTML5, just good ol' regular HTML. That way you won't have to fallback to flash. Also I think it makes more sense that flash would be the fallback for HTML5.

Comment: Oh, nevermind you want multiple file uploads hence the `FileRereferenceList`.

Comment: Yeah, I can do multiple uploads with HTML5 and wanted to use the same interface for flash uploads. I'm just gonna have to use JavaScript SWF Object and replace the file upload button with a flash button if multiple uploads arent available!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the issue here that you can only call `browse()` from an interaction event?

Adobe says:

> In Flash Player 10 and Flash Player 9 Update 5, you can only call this method successfully in response to a user event (for example, in an event handler for a mouse click or keypress event). Otherwise, calling this method results in Flash Player throwing an Error exception.

Try installing the flash debug player and see if you get that exception, or try catching it and displaying an error message.

Comment: Yes, Taurayi already pointed this out in his answer that I selected as the correct answer!

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that part :)